# Local variables break AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

Any time I try to access a local / bootstrapped variable, my AngularJS app stops loading.  Why?  What am I doing wrong?

I am saving a variable, called "bootstrapData," to a page.  I can see the variable by inspecting the element in Chrome...

```
<script type="text/javascript">var bootstrapData = {"userInfo":{"name":"Joe Blow","emailAddress":"joe.blow@nowhere.com","gravatar":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/asdf?s=48&r=x&d=retro"},"token":"asdf"};
```

I am then trying to load that variable.  If this IF block is present, Angular will never load... lots of timeouts, Chrome is basically locked up.  If I comment it out, and reload, the app (and my local variable) will load fine...

```
angular.module('myApp').
factory('Identity',
['$window', 'Profile',
    function($window, Profile){
        var _currentUser;

        if (!_currentUser && !!$window.bootstrapData) {
            console.log('Loading user from bootstrap data');
            _currentUser = new Profile();
            angular.extend(_currentUser, $window.bootstrapData.userInfo);
            $window.bootstrapData = null;
        }

        return {
            currentUser: _currentUser,
            isAuthenticated: function(){
                return !!this.currentUser && this.currentUser.token && this.currentUser.token.length > 0;
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

The profile service itself is empty... just a placeholder for resource objects...

```
angular.module('myApp').
    factory('Profile',
    //['$resource',
    //    function($resource){
    //
    //        var _profileResource = $resource('/api/users/:id', { _id: "@id" }, {
    //            update: { method: 'PUT', isArray: false }
    //        });
    //
    //        return _profileResource;
    //    }
    //]
    function(){
        var _profileResource = {};

        return _profileResource;
    }
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "timeouts"? Is it frozen? Also, what is the injected `Profile` service - can you share its code? Things work fine for me with a mocked up `Profile`: http://plnkr.co/edit/MvcECT0bdN47mkOZJE4j?p=preview

Comment: @NewDev: With the IF statement present, Chrome slows to a crawl as if it was locked up.  Pieces of the site (other unrelated partials... nav, etc.), which normally load in < 10 ms take 3-4 seconds.  Eventually the whole page times out.

Comment: The missing piece is the `Profile` service that you inject (what is `Notifier`?). When you inject a service, it is an object - for you to do `new Profile()` this object needs to be a constructor function. Is this what you have?

Comment: @NewDev: Sorry about that... added the wrong snippet.  Yes, the Profile is a constructor.

Comment: Except it's not - it's an empty object `{}` - the one you are returning - `_profileResource`. You then call `new` on an empty object.

Comment: @NewDev: The second argument in the Profile factor is a function.  Is this not what you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above works fine (see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MvcECT0bdN47mkOZJE4j?p=preview)), if one makes certain assumptions about what the injected `Profile` service is, since it is used as a constructor function `new Profile()`.

Specifically, if it was defined as follows - I am changing the names to make it clearer what I am referring to:

```
.factory("ProfileSvc", function ProfileFactory(){
  function Profile(){
    // constructor function
  }

  return Profile;
});
```

Then, the injected instance of `ProfileSvc` service would be the constructor function `function Profile(){...}`:

```
.factory("anotherSvc", function(ProfileSvc){

   // ProfileSvc here is a function object
   var profile = new ProfileSvc();
});
```

So, what is `function ProfileFactory`?

This is just a function that creates a `ProfileSvc` instance. It could just as well be an anonymous function. And since, at least in this simple example, you are just returning an object - a function object - you could have also written it as `.constant`

```
.constant("ProfileSvc", function Profile(){ });
```

or as `.value`:

```
.value("ProfileSvc", function Profile(){ });
```

`.factory`, `.service`, `.value`, and `.constant` are just different ways to create the injected *singleton* service instance.